# Setup LAMP using 'Google Cloud Platform' Deployment Manager, is it possible to edit with Cloud Shell?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, lamp, google-cloud-shell, google-deployment-manager

I used Deployment Manager to create a LAMP Stack for phpMyAdmin. Is it possible to access files on the VM from the Google Cloud Shell? If so, how would I navigate to the files in Google Cloud Shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start Cloud Shell, it provisions a Google Compute Engine virtual machine running a Debian-based Linux operating system. Cloud Shell instances are provisioned on a per-user, per-session basis. The instance persists while your Cloud Shell session is active; after an hour of inactivity, your session terminates and its VM, discarded. For more on usage quotas, refer to the limitations guide [1](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works).

Yes you can access your LAMP VM-Instance using the cloud shell command as shown below:
gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "us-central1-a" "vm-name" --project "project-id".

Note: (Please replace the zone , vm-name and project-id as per your naming conventions).

Please follow the link [2](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-to) to get more information on Cloud Shell How to Guides.